# How can I find keywords in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I'm user of sublime text.

I want to get the file name which include specific keyword.

I always find file name using grep command.

ex)

```
$ find . -type f -print | xargs grep "apple" /dev//null | cut -d: -f1 | sort -i | uniq
```

I want to do same operation in sublime text.

How can I do same operation in sublime text ?

Comment: Do you want to search the whole system or only in a specific project?

Comment: I want to search only in a specific project.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 2):

You can press `ctrl + shift + f` and search a keyword in your project folder. It will show you the files containing the keyword

Check http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html 
for details

Answer (score 0):

Sublime has a great feature called 'goto anything', which allows you to search both files and file contents within your project.

If you press CTRL+P (windows; Mac I believe uses shortcut CMD+P) a search panel will open, and you may type the keyword contained in the filename, which will return a list of files containing your keyword. In my experience and understanding, filename matches are returned with a higher priority than matches for file contents.

Use your keyboards arrow keys to highlight a result in the list. Pressing enter will select/open that result.

SublimeText.com has a brief overview of the Goto Anything feature on the homepage, and more information is available on the official documentation.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"